# How to pick data from a form into the backend?

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, forms, backend

I've created a new menu on the backend, which has a form. I need to pick the form's data and show them in the same .phtml or another, I don't mind. But the fact is that I can't do a `<form action="" method="POST">` because when I click on the button and the page is refreshed, it returns me to the main control pannel, so I can't pick the data. And when I try to send the data to another .phtml, it happens to me the same, maybe it's because I'm putting the second .phtml (the phtml with de $_POST vars) in the wrong directory, but I'm not sure. Both .phtmls are in the same folder: `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template`

Comment: You should add valid route to form action. Also you should have form_key field in your form otherwise you will be taken to dashboard.

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov I see. I will search information about how to do it with the 'form_key' then. Thanks!!

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov Ok, I've read about what you said but it still happens the same. In the form action I put <?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?> and I added an input hidden like: <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<? echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" /> but it continues going to the dashboard... Do you see something wrong? Do you know how to put it in other way? Or I don't know what to do now.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $this->getFormAction(); is not enough, you have to set it before that. See BOOMER's response for a hint what your action should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Petar stated secret form key is enabled and you are being reverted back to the dashboard.

You can determine if this is enabled by viewing the table `core_config_data` and viewing the XPath: `admin/security/use_form_key` if it is set to 1, then it is enabled and is advised to keep it as such as it is a security measure.

Example:

`echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("module_name/controller_name/action_name/",array("param1"=>1,"param2"=>2));`

Take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Session::getFormKey`, which is referenced by adminhtml/url. This should give you more insight into how those URLs are generated.

Also, in your .phtml use the hidden input field as such:

`<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!! I put that input hidden with Mage::getSingleton('core/session') and now works. Thank you both.